# Change Database Values with one submit click PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I am tired of this code. Really. I have been working yesterday to get this fixed and it's just not working. I would appriciate if anyone would give them their input.

I found an old CMS with some great features. However, that CMS is from 2008 and is still running on MySQL and is not being updated anymore. So I took a few scripts out of it. One is being able to adjust multiple database rows `on` and `off` with just 1 click on the submit button.

The database looks like this.

[image]

The value means on or off. In dutch it is `aan` and `uit`. I'm making a Dutch CMS so I'm creating it in Dutch language for the most part so my customer can understand it too.

The code from the 2008 CMS looks like this: http://pastebin.com/EkmB8rFr (I'm pasting it in Pastebin because it's messy code and SO is too small for this).

So my job is to convert this 2008 code into 2016 code with all the SQL injections fixed and all. Here's my result:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['opslaan'])) {
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM settings');
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $_POST[$row["id"]];
            $row = $row["id"];
            $stmt1 = $dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE settings SET value = ? WHERE id = ?');
            $stmt1->bind_param('ss', $id, $id);
            $stmt1->execute();
        }

        //header('Location: index.php?page=instellingen');
    } else {
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY id ASC');
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Laatst gewijzigd</th>
            <th>Waarde</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["code"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["updated"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <select name="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
                    <option value="aan"<?php if($row["value"] == "aan") {echo ' selected';} ?>>Aan</option>
                    <option value="uit"<?php if($row["value"] == "uit") {echo ' selected';} ?>>Uit</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" name="opslaan">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

This code is just not working like the 2008 code and I just don't know what is going on. **The error is that it puts the ID in the database and not the value of the `<select>`.**

---

**The output should be like this:**

[image]

Comment: this isthe problem `$stmt1->bind_param('ss', $id, $id);`

Comment: @Dagon Got it fixed, thanks for your input Dagon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some things are mixed up in your update. I think this should work better:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $id = $row["id"];                       // get the id from the row
    $value = $_POST[$id];                   // find the corresponding POST value

    $stmt1 = $dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE settings SET value = ? WHERE id = ?');

    $stmt1->bind_param('ss', $value, $id);  // Bind the correct variables here
    $stmt1->execute();
}
```

Comment: dont tell me not to panic, ill panic if i want to ahrhrherhrharharhjeahrakwrkescrjmeuicyhtuiawmtlch,o

Comment: Ah, looks like that fixed the issue. I guess I can't get my yesterday back, but you just made my evening. Thank you, Don't Panic!

Comment: @Dagon so why the pause *h,o* ?